# CarouFREDsel filter / CSS issue

Tags: jquery, css, caroufredsel

I'm using the carouFREDsel jQuery carousel plugin in a responsive (html5 boilerplate) layout. The size of the visible item therefore does change.

My HTML is as follows:

```
 <div class="portfolio-right">
  <div class="portfolio-img-container">
     <div class="portfolio-img"><img  src="img/purple-ink-likes-1.jpg" /></div>
     <div class="portfolio-img"><img src="img/purple-ink-likes-1.jpg" /></div>
     <div class="portfolio-img"><img src="img/purple-ink-likes-1.jpg" /></div>
     <div style="clear:both; visibility: hidden;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using the last DIV with style "clear: both" to ensure that the .portfolio-right shrinks to it's contents (it has a border that surrounds the visible item in the carousel).

CSS:

```
div.portfolio-right
{
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
  border: 8px solid #E6E6E9;
}
```

Either I need to find a way to make the container shrink to it's contents otherwise, or get the filter certain items in carouFREDsel working (for some reason I can't).

```
$(".portfolio-img-container").carouFredSel({
circular : true,
auto : false,
responsive  : true,
scroll      : 1,
items       : {
    filter : ".portfolio-img",
    visible     : 1,
    width       : 200,

},
    pagination: ".portfolio-img-pagination"
});
```

Basically my problem is the filter option won't work, with either classes or :visible selectors. The final DIV with style "clear:both" therefore appears in the pagination.

Am I missing something, and is there perhaps a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the HTML5 boilerplate, there is a handy builtin float clear helper class `.clearfix`.

You just need to apply .clearfix to the container that has the floated elements. Here's the class and comments from the Boilerplate:

```
    /*
     * Clearfix: contain floats
     *
     * For modern browsers
     * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
     *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
     *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
     *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
     * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
     *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
     */

    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after {
        content: " "; /* 1 */
        display: table; /* 2 */
    }

    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }
```